# How do you make bootstrap nav top-level button clickable link for desktop but not mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

Bootstrap's default menu behavior is as an activator that works great for mobile devices but doesn't work for desktops if you want the top-level button clickable as a link while at the same time able to activate the dropdown menu upon hover Adding 'disabled' to the link class gets desktop working but breaks mobile, small devices as the dropdown no longer expands, just loads the URL.

To get the click on hover for desktops I added the recommended CSS to the stylesheet.

```
/* iPad & larger display on hover */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I set the link nav code adding the disabled class as:

```
<a href="somepage.php" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Some Page <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

The above gets it working for screens 768px or wider. What I cannot figure out is how to disable the dropdown class for small devices. If it is there then clicking on the item loads the page (somepage.php) as opposed to revealing the sub-items under somepage.php.

Expanded the menu code looks like:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown <?php if ( $this_file == "somepage.php" ) { echo ' active '; } ?>">
    <a href="somepage.php" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Some Page <span class="_caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu min-width" role="menu">
      <li class="mobile-only"><a href="somepage.php" <?php if ( $this_file == "somepage.php" ) { echo "class=\"active\""; } ?>>Some Page</a></li>
      <li><a href="item2.php" <?php if ( $this_file == "item2.php" ) { echo "class=\"active\""; } ?>>Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="item3.php" <?php if ( $this_file == "item3.php" ) { echo "class=\"active\""; } ?>>Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

The purpose of the mobile-only item is to give the visitor an option to get to the page once the parent is working as a click activator only.

I tried messing with the bootstrap.css disabled class in the stylesheet but that has no effect on the mobile problem. I searched through the bootstrap.js file and found some references to 'disabled' but don't know enough javascript to mess with this.

Comment: make snippet or jsffidle for more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? Make the active one visible only if >768px and the disabled one visible if <768px.

```
<a href="somepage.php" class="visible-xs-12 dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Some Page <span class="caret"></span></a>

<a href="somepage.php" class="hidden-xs-12 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Some Page <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) (use hidden-xs and visible-xs)

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown <?php if ( $this_file == "somepage.php" ) { echo ' active '; } ?> visible-xs  " >
        <a href="somepage.php" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Some Page <span class="caret"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown <?php if ( $this_file == "somepage.php" ) { echo ' active '; } ?> hidden-xs">
        <a href="somepage.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Some Page <span class="_caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu min-width" role="menu">
          <li class="mobile-only"><a href="somepage.php" <?php if ( $this_file == "somepage.php" ) { echo "class=\"active\""; } ?>>Some Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="item2.php" <?php if ( $this_file == "item2.php" ) { echo "class=\"active\""; } ?>>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="item3.php" <?php if ( $this_file == "item3.php" ) { echo "class=\"active\""; } ?>>Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: The first answer was in the right direction, but minus the '-12' as you pointed out. Before posting the question I had created a couple classes, .mobile-only and .desktop-only which I tried but couldn't get to work on small devices properly. And of course I'd completely forgotten about the .hidden and .visible classes. Thx it seems to be working.

Comment: Although the menu, all 4 top level buttons work perfectly on my smartphone and desktop normal width, if I squeeze the browser to force the mobile menu (< 768 px ) get some funky behavior. It works perfectly if on the home page. Click on the hamburger, click on a toplevel and the menu expands. If I click on one of the secondary main menu pages, it correctly reaches the page. However - once on that page if I click on the hamburger it clicks open and closes instantaneously. Yes this sequence works on the smartphone.

Comment: can you add please, in your post the piece of code that cause trouble.

Comment: I would but ... Yesterday afternoon after making the changes, I tested religiously before adding the last comment. The menu operated perfectly when on the home page, but with the browser narrowed < 768 if on other pages clicking on the hamburger icon bounced the menu open/shut immediately. Well - oddly enough this morning I tested again and regardless how narrow I make the browser it is working perfectly. How would you explain the inconsistency? Restart browser, hosting, gerbils?